# Volusion API - Retrieve Daily Unprocessed Ordres

Tags: volusion

The answer to my question should be relatively simple - but I can't seem to find a simple answer.  I'm trying to find a way to regularly connect to Volusion API to retrieve orders in a manner that assures no duplicates and no missing orders.  However, because of the way that queries must be written I'm finding it difficult: 1) You can't use comparisons in queries (greater than, less than, etc.) and 2) The date fields require a full date/time with HHmmss.  3) There is a limit on the number of orders retrieved with each query.  If you query against a date/time, for example, you usually can only get one order, because I can't use a comparative function.  I saw one post here that suggested iterating through order ID's until no data is received.  Has anyone found an easier way to accomplish order retrieval with Volusion API?